# Conditional STRING variable Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

I have a indicator alert that triggers from multiple `OR` conditions. The alert message should be dynamic and correspond to which condition was met.
Is it possible to create a conditional string variable using `IF` in Pine Script?

For example:

```
Stringvar = ""
Stringvar = if (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and perfectSetup and setupCount == 9)
     "Bullish Perfect 9"
else (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and not perfectSetup and setupCount == 9)
     "Bullish IMP9",
else (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and setupCount == 13)
     "Bullish Extended 13",
else (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and not perfectSetup and setupCount == 9)
     "Bearish IMP9",
else (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and perfectSetup and setupCount == 9)
     "Bearish Perfect 9",
else (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and setupCount == 13)
     "Bearish Extended 13"
```

This doesn't work, but the logic of it is the basic premise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional operators (`condition ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse`). It would look something like this:

```
stringVar = (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and perfectSetup and setupCount == 9) ? "Bullish Perfect 9" 
          : (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and not perfectSetup and setupCount == 9) ? "Bullish IMP9" 
          : (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and setupCount == 13) ? "Bullish Extended 13" 
          : (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and not perfectSetup and setupCount == 9) ? "Bearish IMP9" 
          : (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and perfectSetup and setupCount == 9) ? "Bearish Perfect 9" 
          : (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and setupCount == 13) ? "Bearish Extended 13" 
          : na
```

**OR** use the operator `:=` to give a new value to a variable.

```
stringVar = ""

if (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and perfectSetup and setupCount == 9)
     stringVar := "Bullish Perfect 9"
if (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and not perfectSetup and setupCount == 9)
     stringVar := "Bullish IMP9"
and so on...
```

**Edit:**

```
if (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and perfectSetup and showSetup and setupCount == 9) or (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and perfectSetup and showSetup and setupCount == 9) or (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and setupCount == 13) or (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and setupCount == 13)
     alert(stringVar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the 1st logic and it works. But when I plug it into an _alertcondition_ I get an error. 
`alertcondition((setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and perfectSetup and showSetup and setupCount == 9) or (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and perfectSetup and showSetup and setupCount == 9) or (setupLong > 0 and setupShort == 0 and setupCount == 13) 
     or (setupShort > 0 and setupLong == 0 and setupCount == 13), title="TD Setup Count", message=stringVar)`

**Cannot call 'alertcondition' with 'message'=series[string]. The argument should be of type: const string**

Comment: You should use alert() function instead which allows series strings.

Comment: alert() unfortunately not the use-case im looking for. :(

Comment: It's not possible to use dynamic alert messages using alertcondition().

Comment: If you ever decide to use the alert() function, you can use the code I added to my answer that I edited just now.

Comment: So I've done some experimenting with alert().

Comment: I initially thought this function meant alerts were always turned on for the indicator. But I see now you can still save and delete them like alertcondition. Sorry for the misunderstanding.
 Its a good solution. 
Thanks